# finding a possible combination of 2 adjacent array elements of an alternately sorted array

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, sorting

as per usual, I've searched around google and here for an answer, but couldn't find anything that helps me. Keep in mind it's **NOT** for homework, I'm studying for a test and struggling to complete the answer for this question.
There's an alternately sorted array, meaning, the even index elements are sorted and the odd index elements are sorted as well (from smallest to biggest numebr).
For example:

```
int a[] = {1,2,5,3,6,10,9};
```

Now, the question asks to write a boolean method, that receives an array and a number, x, and returns true if the number is a possible combo of 2 adjacent "tiles" and false if not. For example:

```
x = 9; 
FindX(a,9) -> true;
a[3](3) + a[4](6) = 9.
```

I've written my method, and it seems to work with a number that **IS** a possible combo, but when it should return false it gets stuck when the number is in the range of 2 possible combos.

```
  public static boolean FindX(int a[], int x){

    if (a.length==1) { // The question specifies if it's an array with 1 element is should return false. 
        return false;
    }

    int i=(a.length-1)/2; // The middle index
    int i2=i+1; // The adjacent index
    for (; i>=0 && i2<a.length;){ // beginning of loop, if either index is out of bounds, terminates look
        if (a[i]+a[i2]==x) { // once you reach the proper index (when x is within) it returns true
            return true;
        }

        else if (a[i]+a[i2]>x){ // if x is smaller than current combo, make the new index in the new bounds
            i = (i/2)+1;
            i2 = i+1;
        }

        else if (a[i]+a[i2]<x){ // same as above boolean, but opposite situation
            i = (i2+a.length)/2;
            i2 = i+1;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Whenever I input a possible combination, it does work. But if for example I put 14, which i between 9 (=a[3]**(3)** + a[4]**(6)**) and 16 (=a[4]**(6)** + a[5]**(10)**) it loops forever and I can't think of a proper way to exit when that occurs. If the number is out of possible combos but not in the range, it does return false, but for in-between numbers I am stuck.
Answer must be a efficient as possible in both memory and time complexity.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I only can think of O(N*logN) solution. Not sure if it's already fast (efficient) enough for you.

Comment: @ThariqNugrohotomo Linear search will work trivially, so we need to improve upon that. It turns out a binary search works fine.

Comment: What I mean by O(N*logN) is combining both linear & binary search. So for-each of element in odd-index (linear), I will find its 'pair' from element in the even-index (binary).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You implemented a binary search incorrectly: `i` and `i2` point to the middle and "middle plus one," while you should be keeping one index pointing at the beginning and one to the end of the valid range.

To implement this correctly, first consider an imaginary array composed of sums of adjacent items:

```
int a[] = {1,2,5,3,6,10,9};
int s[] = { 3,7,8,9,16,19};
```

This imaginary array would have `a.length-1` elements, and it would be sorted in ascending order.

This observation replaces two alternately sorted "inconvenient" sequences with a single fully sorted "convenient" sequence. You can find an answer to your problem by searching this sequence using binary search.

You don't need to create this array explicitly. Write a classic binary search implementation, for indexes `0` through `a.length-2`, inclusive, but instead of writing `s[mid] < x` write `a[mid]+a[mid+1] < x`.

Answer (score 1):

As per dasblinkenlight suggestion, A simple binary search implementation can cater this requirement. it is efficient

```
public class combo {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        int a[] = {1,2,5,3,6,10,9};
        System.out.println(FindX(a, 14));
    }

    public static boolean FindX(int a[], int x){

        if (a.length==1) { // The question specifies if it's an array with 1 element is should return false. 
            return false;
        }

        int mid = a.length/2;
        int toSearchFrom = 0;
        int toSearchTill = 0;

        if(a[mid-1]+a[mid] < x){
            toSearchFrom = mid;
            toSearchTill = a.length - 1;       
        } else if(a[mid-1]+a[mid] > x){
            toSearchFrom = 0;
            toSearchTill = mid - 1; 
        }

        for(int i=toSearchFrom; i < toSearchTill; i++){
            if(a[i] + a[i+1] == x){
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

}
```

> Sample Input 1 - 19 Output = true
>
> Sample Input 2 - 14 Output = false
>
> Sample Input 3 - 3 Output = true

Comment: Appreciate your answer, but when I tried it with a number that is a combination of last and last-1 tiles, I recieved false whilst I should've gotten true.
edit: for exmaple, trying with 19

Comment: Trying 19, gives true.

Comment: No, it was never edited. if edited, you can see last edited at.